# Find the inverse to the matrices in group $G_M$ denoted by...

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $G_M$ denote the $2\times2$ matrices of the form $$A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are elements of $Z_3$ and $a$ is not equal to zero. Find the inverse of each one of the matrices belonging to this group.

---

I know that the matrix inverse is on the form as the matrix A above. One of the matrices belonging to the group $G_M$ is

$$B=\binom{2\ 2}{0\ 1}\qquad$$
since if a and b is in $Z_3$ then 0<=a,b<=2 with a>0.
The matrix multiplication gives me
$$B*A =\binom{2a\ 2b+2}{0\ 1}\qquad=\binom{1\ 0}{0\ 1}\qquad=I$$

Now i can solve the equation
$$2a=1 (in Z_3)$$
and
$$2b+2=0 (in Z_3) <=> 2b=1 (in Z_3)$$.

So, these equations tells us, since it equal to 1, that a and b are the multiplicative inverses to 2. Therefore I can with Euclid algoritm find a and b, since these equations tells us that$$2a-1=3k <=> 2a-3k_1=1 (in Z)$$
and
$$2b-1=3k <=> 2b-3k_2=1 (in Z)$$
From here we can see that **GCD(2,3)=1** and the euclid algoritm tells us that it excist two integers x,y in $Z$ such
$$2x+3y=1$$

This gives my

$3=2*1+1$

$2=1*2$
and therefore
$$1=3+(-1)*2=3+2*2$$

Furhtemore, since $3=0$ in $Z_3$ we get that
$$2*2=1 (in.Z_3)$$

this tells us that x=2. And since the solution above will be the same for the equations $2a=1$ and $2b=1$ in $Z_3$, we can tell that **a=b=2**. Putting this in A gives us the inverse matrix

$$A=\binom{2\ 2}{0\ 1}\qquad$$
but it's wrong. They say that b=1. Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: since $G_M$ denote the set 2x2 matrices of the form as matrix A above, B must be equal to A for some $a$ and $b$ in $Z_3$. There are six of the matrices belonging to the group $G_M$ and B is one of them.

Comment: Well, just checking $B^2=I$ (in $\mathbb{Z}_3$), it seems as if you are right. Maybe "they" are wrong?

Comment: Yes i know. And if i take the matrix product B*A i will get the $I$ also:$$\binom{2*2\ 2*2+2}{0\ 1}\qquad=\binom{4\ 6}{0\ 1}\qquad=\binom{1\ 0}{0\ 1}\qquad $$

EDIT: Just as u said. B=A so the multiplication B^2 u said was the same multiplication :)

Comment: oh sorry. Did missclick on 1 instead of "a" in the matrix A. @Jlamprong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, its inverse in general view is $$A^{-1}=\frac1a\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -b \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}$$.

Since the elements of your matrix are in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ then $$A^{-1}=a^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -b \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix},$$
where $a^{-1}$ is the element in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ such that $aa^{-1}\equiv 1\mod3$ while $-b$ is  the element in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ such that $b+(-b)\equiv 0\mod3$. It can be seen easily that $1^{-1}=1$, $2^{-1}=2$, $-1=2$, and $-2=1$

In your special case, you have $a=b=2$, i.e., $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$ so
 $$A^{-1}=2^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
as you got.

Comment: You are very wellcome... :D